# Linux self recovering DHCP after really long downtime?

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp, centos6, centos7, networkmanager

I have a few CentOS 6/7 systems (non-production, experimental purposes) that have been configured to use DHCP for their IP address. Last week there was a big network disruption and I found that those systems had lost their IP address and the DHCP client had terminated. I guess after too many/too long retries.

What is the *proper* way to make it try to recover forever?
Is there a dhcp client setting that can do this? Or should I add a cron entry that does something like 'ifup eth0' every hour? Or is there a much better way to do this?

I know CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 do these things differently and I'm looking for answers for both these cases.

---

Update:

For now I have created this script (which I put in /etc/cron.hourly/ ) that seems to work in the specific situation of CentOS 6.
This is probably not the best solution but it "Works on my machine".

```
#!/bin/bash

IF=eth0

ifconfig ${IF} | fgrep 'inet addr' > /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    echo "Network is dead, trying restart"
    ifup ${IF}
fi
```

Still looking for the proper way to do this so I do not think this is the right answer to my question.

Comment: I have not tested this, but I believe your answer would be somewhere in the man page of `dhclient.conf` as you can define default lease options that can override what the client is told by the dhcpd.  Specifically I would look at the `interface` stanza options around lease time and change timeouts.

Comment: As an FYI, the renewal phase (T1) and rebinding phase (T2) are a function of the lease time. For a DHCP client in the rebinding phase (T2) the client will release it's ip address and return to the INIT (no ip address) state after the T2 phase expires.

Answer (score 5):

Both CentOS 6 and 7 should accept the PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT option within /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg* files .e.g.

```
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=yes
ONTBOOT=yes
DEVICE=eth0
```

This instructs the ifup-eth script to run the dhclient without the (default) *-1* option

```
if is_true "${PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT}"; then
    ONESHOT="";
else
    ONESHOT="-1";
fi;
...
DHCLIENTARGS="${DHCLIENTARGS} ${ONESHOT} -q ${DHCLIENTCONF} -lf ${LEASEFILE} -pf /var/run/dhclient-${DEVICE}.pid"
```

With that option dhclient will try once. From the man page

```
-1 Try once to get a lease. One failure, exit with code 2.
```

Without that option dhclient should retry occasionally (every 5 minutes by default) again from dhclient.conf man page

```
retry time;

The retry statement determines the time that must pass after the client 
has determined that there is no DHCP server present before it tries 
again to contact a DHCP server. By default, this is five minutes.
```